# DOMPDF solo rescata el html y no los datos que obtengo de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Necesito extraer a `PDF` el contenido `HTML`de una pagina `inf_ev_003_7.php`

el problema es que  me extrae solamente el `HTML` y no la data que obtengo a través de `SQL` y `PHP` en esta `inf_ev_003_7.php`

`**así es mi código crearPdf.php:**`

```
            <?php
                // Cargamos la librería dompdf que hemos instalado en la carpeta dompdf
                include("../../../config/lib/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
                use Dompdf\Dompdf;

                ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
                error_reporting(E_ALL);

                $rut = $_GET['rut'];
                $ev  = $_GET['ev'];

                // Introducimos HTML de prueba



                 $html=file_get_contents_curl("http://localhost/inf_ev_003_7.php?ev='.$ev.'&rut='.$rut.'");

                echo $html;

                exit;

                // Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
                $pdf = new DOMPDF();

                // Definimos el tamaño y orientación del papel que queremos.
                $pdf->set_paper("letter", "portrait");
                //$pdf->set_paper(array(0,0,104,250));

                // Cargamos el contenido HTML.
                $pdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html));

                // Renderizamos el documento PDF.
                $pdf->render();

                // Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
                $pdf->stream('reporte_evaluacion2.pdf');


                function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
                    $crl = curl_init();
                    $timeout = 5;
                    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
                    curl_close($crl);
                    return $ret;
                }
```

Necesito saber que me falta o que estoy haciendo mal, ya que no obtengo la data rescatada por `sql` y `php`  de mi pagina `inf_ev_003_7.php` en el `pdf`.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sabes que esa data sí está viniendo o que la consulta está funcionando?

Comment: estoy pasando los los parametros por la url en `crearPdf.php` hacia `inf_ev_003_7.php` , pero nose como validar si me estan llegando esos datos de `inf_ev_003_7.php`. tu me podras ayudar?

Comment: En lugar de crear el PDF puedes temporalmente mostrarlo por pantalla. En ese caso comenta todo el código de creación del PDF y demás y haz un simple `echo $html;` viendo lo que mostrará en pantalla. De hecho lo tienes, y luego tienes un `exit` ... no sé por qué.

Comment: si, estaba haciendo la prueba, solo me llega el html, y no la data . el echo html para ver que me esta llegando, y el exit para cerrar el proceso alli, solo obtengo el html de `inf_ev_003_7.php` y no la data.

Comment: ¿ *no la data*  quiere entonces decir que tampoco en el html se muestran los datos del SQL? Si es así es problema de tu código SQL entonces que no está funcionando como esperas.

Comment: si yo ejecuto `inf_ev_003_7.php` funciona correctamente con su php y querys( de forma independiente obtengo la data). 
pero cuando trato de exportar este `inf_ev_003_7.php` con dompdf, solo me extrae el html y no la data que obtengo con sus querys y php.

Comment: Bueno pero en el código tú le envías parámetros: `http://localhost/inf_ev_003_7.php?ev='.$ev.'&rut='.$rut.'` y no se sabe si el código funciona bien con parámetros. Eso depende de cómo manejes esos parámetros y demás... pues supongo que la data depende de esos parámetros, que serán criterios `WHERE`  de tu consulta. Si no los capturas bien la consulta SQL estará fallando. ¿Verificaste eso?

Comment: claro, la data que se muestra en `inf_ev_003_7.php` depende `$ev` y `$rut`  que paso porla url hacia  `inf_ev_003_7.php` para ir a buscar los datos.
lo que nose, es como validar si estan llegando bien hacia  `inf_ev_003_7.php` cuando va a buscar los datos y luego traerlos de vuelta.

Comment: Eso tienes que verlo en el código inicial de `inf_ev_003_7.php`, allí debes validar vía `POST` o vía `GET` que estén presentes los valores `rut` y `ev`, algo parecido a esto que tienes al principio de este archivo: `$rut = $_GET['rut'];
                $ev  = $_GET['ev'];`  pero más serio, usando por ejemplo `empty` para verificar que no están vácíos y devolver las indicaciones adecuadas en esos casos.

Comment: si, los rescato via `GET` al comienzo de `inf_ev_003_7.php`. pero nose como mostrar por pantalla cuando va a buscar a `inf_ev_003_7.php` para ver si llega bien.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así: `$rut = ( empty($_GET['rut']) ) ? NULL : $_GET['rut']; $ev = ( empty($_GET['ev']) ) ? NULL : $_GET['ev'];` Y luego: `if ($rut && $ev) {echo "Hay datos. ev:$ev y rut:$rut";}else{echo "No llegaron los datos";}` Esto sólo como prueba. En la parte 1ª del `if` en un escenario real iría la consulta SQL, la cual debe tener también un flujo controlado de si no hay errores, de si no encuentra datos vacíos, etc.

Comment: estaba leyendo las formas correctas de pasar por GET o POST las variables que incrusto en la URL de `file_get_content_curl`, finalmente encontre con esto:  `ob_start();
  include 'inf_ev_003_7.php';
  $html = ob_get_clean();`  reemplazando el `file_get_content_curl `por el `ob_get_clean();` logro obtener la data, nose si sera el conducto regular, pero de esa forma si la obtengo.

Comment: Cierto cierto, estás usando `cURL`.  Y `ob_get_clean()` es la forma correcta si quieres limpiar el buffer al obtener los datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu tiempo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logre encontrar una solucion reemplazando :

```
   $html=file_get_contents_curl("http://localhost/inf_ev_003_7.php?ev='.$ev.'&rut='.$rut.'");
```

por :

```
     ob_start();
     include 'inf_ev_003_7.php';
     $html = ob_get_clean();
```

no logre encontrar otra forma de rescatar la data mediante la URL, que al parecer es el problema que tenia con 'file_get_contents_curl', con esta correccion logro obtener el html y su data completa.

figuran algunas alertas las cuales no interrumpen su funcionamiento, pero si me gustaria saber a que se deben:

```
 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\config\config.php on line 4787

 Deprecated: Function session_register() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\config\config.php on line 19

 Deprecated: Function session_register() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\config\config.php on line 20
```